# MVC jQuery UI CSS urls not resolving after deployment

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

The title pretty much says it all.
In the jquery-ui.css it defines styles like:

```
ui-widget-content {
border: 1px solid #aaaaaa/*{borderColorContent}*/;
background: #ffffff/*{bgColorContent}*/ url(images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png)/*
color: #222222/*{fcContent}*/;
}
```

This works fine in dev, but once deployed the url no longer resolves. The site is deployed under the default web site in IIS7. So in the browser console I can see that its looking for the image in

```
http:// (servername)/(appName)/Content/images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png
```

instead of

```
http:// (serverName)/(appName)/content/themes/base/images...
```

Here is the bundle config:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css",
            "~/Content/site.css"
));
```

How can I make these URLs resolve correctly?

Comment: Did you bundle your CSS files?

Comment: Yes, they're all bundled.

Comment: Can you post relevant part of your BundleConfig?

Comment: Updated it in the OP.

Comment: Why not use the `<base>` tag in your HTML?

Comment: This link covers the jquery UI example: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification  It's too bad there isn't a way to bundle all of the CSS up into a single bundle without having separate StyleBundles to deal with the base path differences.  Anyone know how?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ufuk's answer got me thinking. Appending the app name to the front of the bundle's virtual path broke all my styles.

The bundle function takes all the CSS files inside the include statement and minifies them into one file located at the URL specified in the bundle's virtual path. The urls specified in the CSS files included in this bundle uses the bundle's given virtual path to build up its URL at runtime. This works fine in dev because dev does not utilize the bundles, it references each css file individually/directly.

The solution was to create a bundle with the correct virtual path:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")):
```

Thanks Ufuk for the advice and guidance.

Comment: Just a note that the style bundle virtual path should be different than the actual location...this got me stuck for a few minutes.

Comment: To confirm, you absolutely *should not* use an actual file of folder path as the bundle name. This will cause IIS to try and load the directory or file instead of the bundle.

Answer (score 3):

You should update your bundle's virtual path like this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/appName/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css",
            "~/Content/site.css"
));
```

This way relative URLs in your CSS file will start from `~/appName`. Keep this in mind if you have other relative URLs in site.css file.

Answer (score 0):

After I updated my solution with nuGet package manager to the newest jqueryui -files, version 1.11, the css-files of jqueryui didn't get loaded. So I checked the BundleConfig class just to notice that jqueryui css was still using old path like:
    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"

I replaced those with:
     "~/Content/themes/base/theme.css"
and then my page was back in business.